# show form data in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

In my application,i am keeping some choices in forms.The choices are check box input and user can click and save the choices.In database saved choice are stored as integer like 1,2,3.How to query the saved value from database and show it in template as their corresponding options.

forms.py

```
OPTIONS = (
    ('1', 'Today'),
    ('2', 'This Week'),
    ('3', 'This Month'),
    ('4', 'This Year'),
    ('5', 'All'),
 )

class ReporForm(forms.ModelForm):
    optons = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=OPTIONS,required=False, initial=0)
```

template

```
{{ reportform.as_p}}
```

Here,if user selected "This week" as their option,then in database the value of "This week" "2" will be saved.

In usual if i query the data from table,it is rendering the value as "2".But i want it to display  "This week" in template.I don't see any tutorial or blog in this way.

I don't know how to do this in Django.

Comment: could you please show your template too?

Comment: @Ghyllebert,updated the template in question,that template is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to retrieve the value of your dictionary in django, you can use the following syntax:

```
ReporForm.get_optons_display()
```

So for example, if you wanted to check if the database query was 'All' or the key '5' you could simply do:

```
if ReporForm.get_optons_display() == 'ALL':
    #do something
```

[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

An excerpt for an example:

Views.py

```
    #Query your database to retrieve your instance of 'ReporForm'
    #I will assume there is a primary key of some type (Reportcode)
    foo = ReporForm.objects.get(ReportCode = 1234)

#Pass foo to the context
context = {'foo':foo}
#Send this context to your render_to_response so it goes to template
```

reportform.html

```
<b>You have selected the option :</b> '{{ foo.get_optons_display }}'
```

Comment: Like @JcKelley said, if you want to show the "This week", user get_optons_display(), django generate this method for you. See 
[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices)

Comment: @JcKelley,In template how to render the value,can you show me how to implement,i don't understand how to implement.

Comment: @MonkL, you would use the same function, get_field_display(). So with your passed instance of 'ReporForm', you would just do {{ ReporForm.get_optons_display }} and that will display 'This Week' or whatever your dictionary value was.

Comment: @JcKelley,sorry to ask you again,in views.py i should write a method for this write.If you have any sample please share it.